# You need to protect children from harm

Tags: support, legal, abuse

I am concerned about a question I saw on Parenting that details the emotional and physical abuse of a five year old child by its mother.

SE should have mechanisms in place to coordinate with the relevant child protection agencies.

I am not asking for SE to initiate the contact. I am asking for SE to have a process in place for child protection agencies to use when contacting SE.

In this case SE should be coordinating with UK charity NSPCC, or UK police, to protect this child from further harm.

I reported the post to NSPCC. They are unable to proceed because there's no mechanism for them to get information from SE.

This means the five year old child continues to be emotionally abused, and is at significant risk of ongoing physical abuse.

Mods on Parenting SE have not been helpful.

Comment: Be interested to hear why this got downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes on meta are used for expressing disagreement with the proposal. So that is the reason for the downvotes in this instance.

Comment: From your [profile in September](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906142108/http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/167162/danbeale): "parentingSE is toxic. Please ban my account." - I suppose you've got an axe to grind with Parenting.SE. I have no idea why you haven't deleted an account there.

Comment: @DeerHunter that probably explains the *"Mods on Parenting SE have not been helpful"* part.

Comment: "hinder any attempt."

Comment: @JonW thanks for clarification around downvotes.

Comment: @DeerHunter this post has nothing to do with my frustrations with Parenting SE.  This post is only about a child who is currently being abused and who is at significant risk of future physical abuse, and my inability to get anything done about it. Asking the question here got several useful responses.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/do-we-have-any-responsibility-to-take-any-action-if-someone-says-theyre-thinkin/6258#6258 ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257710/mod-only-tool-for-posts-that-mention-suicide ...

Comment: You should take this up with authorities outside of SE, period. You did that, which is great. It's not the job of SE to act as middle-man in such instances.

Comment: @Werner Once I've contacted authorities they will need to contact SE.  It is unclear (to those authorities, and to me) where abouts they need to go to make contact with SE. It is unclear what details they'll need to provide to SE to get SE to provide information.

Comment: Surprised to see this question closed.  SE employees have contacted me privately; Se employees have responded to this question; SE users have suggested I point people to this question in future.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that an organization dedicated to this single purpose can't figure out how to contact a company via email to request information relevant to their single purpose. Surely they've dealt with a similar situation before.

Comment: @JoshCaswell and yet they report difficulty interacting with SE.  Importantly, "online" stuff is not their single purpose. Most of their work is with children in real world, away from computers.  Other orgs deal with online abuse - IWF for images of child sexual abuse; CEOP for abuse of children happening online. This is correctly NSPCC's remit, but it's unusual because the evidence and the disclosure is online.  This post here isn't all I'm doing: I've also asked NSPCC why they don't interact with other orgs better.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just to note that we *do* have facilities in place to address situations like this. Talk of suicide, abuse, or other signs obvious harm to oneself or others are handled internally by employees properly equipped to do so.

When anyone sees a situation like this, it is best to [**notify us directly**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) rather than trying to confront users online. A public spectacle in these circumstances can often lead to a *pile-on situation* that can do more harm than handling it privately.

Thank you for bringing up the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just checking: is the "contact us" email link best?  And how should mods handle the question?

Comment: The 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page is the most direct way to assure the post reaches the right person. But if the situation appears to be a more time-sensitive issue than an email would suggest, you have flags, @user comments, chat room pings, and other methods to assure someone sees it in real time. And how mods handle, remove, or otherwise moderate the post simply depends (very much) on what the situation calls for. Moderators have all the tools to moderate for content, so they can remove a post if its presence is causing more harm than good. But that is not *always* the case.

Comment: What happens after you all are contacted? We've had a couple of possible abuse disclosures on IPS.SE I guess it would be a little more reassuring if we had a picture of what the official procedure looks like

Comment: The user *should* be contacted directly via email with an appeal to contact us directly to see if everything is okay, accompanied by some (hopefully) helpful information about how they can receive further direct help offline. If a call-for-help/attention is being removed from the "public spectacle", timely contact should be paramount. Please let me know if there evidence of that not happening.

Answer (score 10):

> This is a bug: lack of interface to protect children from harm

I'm not sure it is really. I don't think there should exactly be an 'interface to protect children from harm' because this seems to be pretty rare *on SE*. Anyway, what 'interface' *could* there be?

> I reported the post to NSPCC. They are unable to proceed because there's no mechanism for them to get information from SE.

However, I'm sure that SE would be able to help if they (or some other official organisation) contacted them (via email) and asked them for any information, **as far as they legally can**. Email is probably the best 'interface' SE could possibly provide I think.

See [Shog's answer to "Do we have any responsibility to take any action if someone says they're thinking about suicide in their post?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6258), where he says:

> For any credible threat of bodily harm - whether targeted at the
>   author themselves or someone else - use the contact us option at the
>   bottom of any page on the site to let us know about this. If need-be,
>   we'll follow up to make sure the situation is handled appropriately.

This fully applies in this case, so it seems SE would help, as far as they can, to get the matter resolved.

Comment: If email is the best interface a simple webpage aimed at child protection officials listing the process they need to follow to get info from SE would be a good start. And SE might want to consider which situations they require a warrant for, or if there are any situations where they don't need a warrant.

Comment: @DanBeale but how is that different from just emailing? They can email, and get the required information.

Comment: Thanks for the link to shog's post! That probably needs to be somewhere more visible.

Comment: @DanBeale you're welcome - but that's what I'm talking about: **SE will do their best if they are contacted**. There shouldn't be a need to do anything extra.

Comment: Orgs don't know that SE will provide any help; orgs don't know that they need to email. A simple webpage describing the process saves time for everyone. And time is important here.

Comment: @DanBeale If they can't find the "contact us" page that's linked to from every page on the site then what makes you think they'd be able to find such a page, even if it existed?

Comment: The contact link is on every page, @DanBeale - I think it's pretty easy to find. That said, you may be overestimating what we can actually do here; we don't collect (much less verify!) much in the way of personal information; ultimately, all we have to go on is the word of the author. We can offer them advice and support, and if contacted we'll certainly do so - beyond that, I'm at a loss as to what you're expecting here.

Comment: What I'm expecting: SE to have a small webpage aimed at law enforcement. I report something to law enforcement, I point them to the post that discloses child abuse, and to the web page.  That web page lists the process that you and they need to follow for you to release what information you have.  That may just be timestamped IP addresses. The webpage would include an email address, a list of information you need, any warrant requirements, etc.

Comment: @DanBeale then link them to this page from now on..? It has official responses and says what to do.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yes, I will.  But still, a web page would be updatable with correct information if things change. And it would give reassurance to child protection agencies.

Answer (score 10):

There already *is* a method to contact the child support / NSPCC etc. And it is what you did - contact them directly.

It is not for Stack Exchange to be responsible for such things. What if there *were* an option and one of the admins / mods *didn't* report it because they weren't aware a particular issue was a crime? Would they be held responsible for neglect?

it's too dangerous to open up such requirements / abilities to this community. If you need to contact a 3rd party about a post then you are free to do so - the site is open to anyone to view without a sign-up requirement so such agencies are able to view all content. And they can get in contact with the administrators directly if they so wish.

Comment: I need to be more clear: I don't want SE to do the initial contacts. In this case NSPCC tried to get in contact with SE but were unable to do so. So I'm asking for SE to have a webpage. When I report child abuse I can point the NSPCC to the declaration of abuse and to SE's page. The SE page would provide process details.

Comment: @DanBeale `NSPCC tried to get in contact with SE but were unable to do so` Why? What prevented them?

Comment: Have a look at the site through the eyes of someone who's never been here before. It's not user friendly to naive users.

Comment: @DanBeale A "contact us" link at the top or bottom of the webpage is pretty standard throughout the entire internet, and it's something that SE follows.  And if they're telling you that they can't figure out how to contact SE, then simply direct them to the contact page.

Comment: @DanBeale If you're after a *specific* 'contact child protection' link or something, then that would be impractical. It's very country-specific, and would open the door for things like "we need a Contact Police" or "Contact Immigration Dept" or "Contact Fraud Bureau".. One global 'Contact Us' is sufficient for this. Heck, if people who work for Child protection don't know how to find a Contact Us link I'd be very surprised. Many of them have 'browsing the whole internet looking for stuff" as their primary job requirement.

Comment: All those agencies will have to comply with SE's policies, so a single page detailing what info SE needs to be able to release info to 3rd parties would suffice.