# As a normal user, how should I act on posts showing a severe level of paranoia or signs of other mental problems?

Tags: discussion, moderation, community

As a normal, unprivileged user, I wonder what I should do if I encounter a post on any SE site which contains signs of severe mental health problems like paranoia or persecution mania, but not necessarily any suicide notes.

Last time when I stumbled over such a post, I left a custom moderator flag explaining that I think the user has mental problems. It was marked helpful later and the post got deleted.

However, I would like to ask whether that was the right way to react or whether I could/should have done something else. I didn't really dare to leave a comment regarding their mental state, as I feared it might worsen the situation. What about technical comments, e.g. if I can explain that something they see as threat is actually normal and why - should I post that? Or just flag it and leave?

Comment: Can I ask which SE site it was? What did the OP write? I don't understand why a total stranger on the internet would care about another stranger's mental problem.

Comment: @Rathony As I said, the post is deleted already. It has been on [ham.se], a SmokeDetector report called my attention. And of course I care about my fellow humans as far as I can. Don't you? I don't want to risk being responsible for bad things somebody does to themselves or others, which is a considerable risk if somebody has mental problems. After all, the SE community is there to help each other.

Comment: Well, I am not against helping each other as I am helping others, too. But do you really think you can solve their problem by leaving a comment? Hmm... Thanks for letting me know the site exists. Let me take a look around. :-)

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268574/you-need-to-protect-children-from-harm

Comment: Also worth looking at even though it was prompted by suicidal talk: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6256

Comment: @JoshCaswell there is similar discussion right here at MSE: [What's the official SE response to serious mentions of suicide in posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/whats-the-official-se-response-to-serious-mentions-of-suicide-in-posts)

Comment: We're not really talking about suicide here though, so leaving a comment about suicide helplines would be more than inappropriate. Using the SE "Contact us" form might also be exaggerated, so only raising a custom mod flag remains as recommended action. Is that really all one should do?

Comment: I know you "ruled out" suicide, but to my mind, the important part of Shog's answer on Meta.Programmers is the idea that if you're not well-versed in handling $SERIOUS_ISSUE, _whatever_ it may be, alerting a moderator is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: @JoshCaswell What can moderators do? Call the police? Come on...

Comment: What can _you_ do, @Rathony?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nothing. Move on.

Comment: Honestly you can't do anything. Mental health issues are *very* complex and you know next to nothing about the circumstances of the person in question. If the question should be closed then flag/vtc but there's nothing you can do specifically with regards to the posters mental health.

Comment: @Rathony Moderators are equipped to quickly contact the community manager team here at SE who, depending on the situation, have a set of processes used to handle what's going on. (Well, "quickly" may vary, but there's at least two avenues for mods to use that go directly to a CM whereas regular users don't have quite the same level of priority access.)

Comment: @AdamLear Well, I am not saying helping them is a bad idea, but that's applicable only when we **assume** they are telling the truth.  The OP  is asking about a severe level of paranoia or signs of other mental problems. As Cai mentioned, there is nothing we can or should do other than flag/vtc if it is off-topic. I saw a few of them, and they seemed to need someone to talk to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators are the sites' exception handlers. When there's a situation that normal channels can't resolve (voting, editing, flagging, etc.) it's the Moderators who need to step in.

I'd say you did exactly the right thing.

Also, to [quote Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285234/as-a-normal-user-how-should-i-act-on-posts-showing-a-severe-level-of-paranoia-o#comment925120_285234):

> Moderators are equipped to quickly contact the community manager team here at SE who, depending on the situation, have a set of processes used to handle what's going on. (Well, "quickly" may vary, but there's at least two avenues for mods to use that go directly to a CM whereas regular users don't have quite the same level of priority access.)